# Window zoom / size after removing external monitor/display

Tags: display, dell, external-monitor, zooming, 4k-monitor

I have a very annoying problem.
When i connect my external display the window sizes and zoom are not correct (Either to big or to small). This can't be fixed with the display application. When i restart while having the display plugged in everything is fine.
I have to unplug the display very often at work and then the display is all messed up again.
Does anyone know how to solve this bug?

Ubuntu version: 17

Laptop: Dell XPS 15.6

Resolution: 4K Ultra HD (3840 x 2160) InfinityEdge touch display

GFX card: NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1050

This issue happens with every external display.

**How to test:**

- Open chrome or something similar
- Plugin your external display (tab sizing etc should be wrong)
- Unplug the external monitor and you will see that everything is normal again

Comment: It can be fixed, actually adjusted independently unless the morroring option is selected. Then there's scaling that may use a slight increase for high resolutions and small screens.

Comment: So how can do this? I tried scaling etc but just not working:)

Comment: Not working is meaningless. Please [edit] and post the hardware info, namely the native resolutions of the internal and external monitors and also the graphics card/chip and which proprietary drivers version you installed, if applicable.

Comment: @MichaelBay I added some extra information.